# How to prevent Google's geocode alert status message?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

```
function initMap() {
      var this_input;
     /* var options = {
  types: ['(cities)'],
  componentRestrictions: {country: "my"}
 };*/
      $("input[name=location]").focusin(function(){
   // alert($(this).attr("id"));
     this_input = $(this).attr("id");
  var input = /** @type {!HTMLInputElement} */(
      document.getElementById(this_input));

  var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);
   var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
  var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
  autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', function() {
    infowindow.close();
    var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
    if (!place.geometry) {
      window.alert("Autocomplete's returned place contains no geometry");
      return;
    }
    var address = '';
    if (place.address_components) {
      address = [
        (place.address_components[0] && place.address_components[0].short_name || ''),
        (place.address_components[1] && place.address_components[1].short_name || ''),
        (place.address_components[2] && place.address_components[2].short_name || '')
      ].join(' ');
    }
    infowindow.setContent('<div><strong>' + place.name + '</strong><br>' + address);
  });
   document.getElementById('submit').addEventListener('click', function() {

   geocodeAddress(geocoder);
  });


  });//end of input[name=location]
}
```

ABove is my script to show autocomplete on whichever `focusin` textfield with `name ='location'`. That works fine. Its just that, I've already removed a bunch of `geocoder` code , that alerts status of the location entered, namely: ZERO_RESULTS.

But it keeps alerting, QUERY OVER LIMIT, ZERO_RESULT messages. I don't know from where these messages are prompted thus how do I stop this?

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue.

Answer (score 3):

You need to start with your geocodeAddress function.

Your function would probably like  this

```
  function geocodeAddress(geo) {
    geo.geocode({address:search}, function (results, status)
      { 
        // If that was successful
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            ...
        }
        // ====== Decode the error status ======
        else {
            // Make alert when error occurs
            window.alert(status); // <-- delete this line or modify it                
        }
      }
    );
  }
```

You must be making alert with the error status in your geocode handler.
So, you should modify handler code.